Why is Outlook Formatting this Column Header into text wrapped (2 lines) when pasting from Excel and how can I stop it?
I'm trying to spend a moment to figure out how to block Outlook from messing with my tables each time I paste one. Basically, each time, I have my data so there is no "text wrapping" and its same width per row and then each column I use "autofit". When I paste into Outlook from Excel, it always finds a column or two and makes the row 2x height and does "text wrapping".
Before I tackled the problem, I wanted to do some troubleshooting and I found quite a weird results during testing and I'd like help understanding as it may help resolve problem as well.
Lets take this basic 2x tables that I made:

This is how it looks when I pasted them separately into Outlook:

What gives? Why would it text wrap the 'Short Col Header" but not the "Long Column Header A"?
Bonus: How can I stop it from happening!

Note: Converting to a table isn't really an option, its more work then just adjusting in Outlook.

I do this multiple times daily, and I'm fairly efficient at it, so unless I can just disable/fix this via a setting Outlook any other method that requires an "extra step" is likely not worth it to me, but feel free to share tips!

Pasting tables into Outlook has always had odd behavior and I usually have to rearrange the cells to get them to fit. But, how are you pasting them: using source formatting or destination formatting? What is the default font size in Outlook?

@music2myear I mean, I just copy data using CTRL+C and CTRL+V. I almost never touch "special paste" or "font" etc. Just wish Outlook could understand another MSFT Office Product and just copy the data exactly the same. I was hoping a setting might fix it, but based on the only answer, I don't think I'm in luck.

Outlook uses different padding in the table cells. If you inspect the screenshot closely, you can see that in Excel, the words extend much closer to the table border, and in Outlook the gap between the characters and the table border is wider. As a result, the text doesn't fit into the column width after pasting the cells into Outlook, and the text gets wrapped.
Workaround 1: make the Excel column wider before copying.
Workaround 2: make the Outlook column wider after pasting.
Workaround 3: select "Autofit" in the Layout ribbon with the table selected in Outlook

Before Autofit

After Autofit

Edit after comments:  There is really no easy solution since Outlook emails use HTML, and the built-in (hard-coded, baked into the product CSS) settings for tables simply include more padding than an Excel table uses. Excel is not -- and has never been, nor will it ever be -- a desktop publishing tool, and an expectation that a spreadsheet that excels (pun intended) at number crunching and analysis should be on par with HTML settings of an app with a completely different purpose is, frankly, a bit unrealistic.
If exact positioning and line breaks are important, copy as picture and paste as picture. In all other cases, you will have to make do with the status quo and use workarounds.
/rant

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

I'll accept if nothing better comes. Workaround 1 is a waste, because now my data is not correct in Excel (which I spent time autofitting). #2 is what I currently do, every time, I make cols bigger then autofit. #3 doesn't apply as I don't want to convert to table.

Sounds like I'm just SOL and have to keep doing what I'm doing. Ridiculous that Excel and Outlook can't play better together. Maybe I'll look into a button for an Add-In I run, but again, might not be worth it, I'm pretty quick at making columns larger and autofit, as I do it every day, multiple times a day...

I added some more explanation to my answer.

I accepted because I think you're correct, I'm SOL and just have to continue w/ #2. It is a great answer, thank you :).

To others: Please don't send pictures of tables unless you have a very specific reason, pictures of tables make me cry as I often need to re-create the data manually.
